# Clang Front End Actions - Linking Problem on Fedora

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, fedora, clang++

I'm following [this guide](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) on how to make a front end action for clang, working on a Fedora 38 system.

After some trial and error I arrived at this cmake file for the example (the one provided in the guide doesn't work for me as-is). I'm not an expert on cmake so there could be some mistakes or redundancies in there of course.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.0)
project(clang-test VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_package(Clang REQUIRED HINTS "${CLANG_CMAKE_PATH}")
include(AddLLVM)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED HINTS "${LLVM_CMAKE_PATH}")

include("/usr/lib64/cmake/clang/AddClang.cmake")

include_directories(SYSTEM "${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS};${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  Support
  )

add_clang_executable(clang-test clang-test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(clang-test
  PRIVATE
  clangAST
  clangBasic
  clangFrontend
  clangSerialization
  clangTooling
  )

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
```

`clang-test.cpp` just contains the source from the guide.

Now my problem is this, when I call `make` I get the following output:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable clang-test
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/clang-test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++ -g -rdynamic  -Wl,-rpath-link,  -Wl,--gc-sections "CMakeFiles/clang-test.dir/clang-test.cpp.o" -o clang-test  -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN/../lib64:/usr/lib64" /usr/lib64/libLLVM-16.so -lclangAST -lclangBasic -lclangFrontend -lclangSerialization -lclangTooling 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangAST: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangBasic: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangFrontend: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangSerialization: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangTooling: No such file or directory
clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/clang-test.dir/build.make:101: clang-test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xxx/projects/clang-test/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:221: CMakeFiles/clang-test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xxx/projects/clang-test/build'
make: *** [Makefile:114: all] Error 2
```

Using `dnf` I have installed `clang`, `clang-devel`, `clang-libs`, `clang-tools-extra` and `clang-tools-extra-devel`. I have tried variants of `find / -print | grep -i libClang` to see if the libraries exist, but either I'm searching for the wrong thing or they don't exist on my system.

Which package should I install to get the correct libraries on my system? Or do I need to build clang from source if I want to build a front end action or plugin on Fedora? Or did I just go "blind" and I'm missing something trivial?

Comment: I think the linker is unable to locate the required library files in the specified search paths. You can run this command to see your SEARCH_DIRS: `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`. Then you can add it manually. If that doesn't work.. Then I have no idea :)

Comment: You also mentioned that you used `dnf` to download the package and didn't find it. Try `sudo find / -name "someFile.so" 2>/dev/null` . If you don't know what the file is called (it's operating system specific) then you have to look at `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` manually and try to find the files. Alternatively, download the files from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/clang-devel).

Comment: Thank you @EldinurtheKolibri for the comments! You know, it never occured to my chicken brain that the library could be called something different on my system. Thanks to you I broadened my search and found the answer. On Fedora it seems you need to link with ```/usr/lib64/libclang-cpp.so``` and not what they suggest in the tutorial I was following, which is fair enough since they of course can't cover every system that exists. Now it's working for me - thank you :)

Comment: Ok, great!!!   :)

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev for pointing that out. I'll keep it in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that on my Fedora system the library is called `/usr/lib64/libclang-cpp.so`, so changing the link target in the makefile as follows solves the issue.

```
target_link_libraries(clang-test PRIVATE clang-cpp)
```